# Keypress function in javascript not working

Tags: javascript

```
addEventListener('keypress', ({keyCode}) => {
    switch(keyCode){
        case 87: //up
            alert('press')
        break;
    }
})
```

Why is my keypress not working, if I change it to keydown, it works but keypress does not

Comment: That’s explained in the [documentation](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/keypress_event). The `keypress` event is deprecated, by the way.

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): _"**Describe the problem.** "It doesn't work" isn't descriptive enough to help people understand your problem. Instead, tell other readers what the expected behavior should be. Tell other readers what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it. Use a brief but descriptive summary of your problem as the title of your question."_

Answer (score 2):

See [the documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/keypress_event):

> The `keypress` event is fired when a **key that produces a character value is pressed down**.

(bold added for emphasis)

The reason it does not work is that the Up key does not produce a character. Try here:

```js
document.addEventListener('keypress', ({keyCode}) => {
  console.log("fired", keyCode);
});
```

```html
Click here to focus then try pressing a letter key 
and then try something else like up, or backspace, or Alt.
```

To react to events of other keys use other events such as keydown, or keyup.

Do note that keypress itself is deprecated, MDN has an explicit guidance for that:

> **Warning**: Since this event has been deprecated, you should use [`beforeinput`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/beforeinput_event) or [`keydown`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/keydown_event) instead.

Answer (score 0):

`keypress` is now deprecated ([see documentation here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/keypress_event))

You should now either use [keydown](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/keydown_event) or [keyup](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/keyup_event)

According to the documentation :

> The keyup event is fired when a key is released.

> The keydown event is fired when a key is pressed.

Example :

```js
const keyupInput = document.getElementById('keyup-button')
const keydownInput = document.getElementById('keydown-button')

keyupInput.addEventListener('keyup', ({key, code}) => {
  console.log('keyup', key, code)
})

keydownInput.addEventListener('keydown', ({key, code}) => {
  console.log('keydown', key, code)
})
```

```html
<label>keyup</label>
<input id="keyup-button" />

<label>keydown</label>
<input id="keydown-button" />
```

Comment: Just because something gets deprecated it doesn't instantly breaks stuff.

Comment: The reason why arrow keys don’t work with `keypress` isn’t that `keypress` is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

`keypress event` is deprecated. Although some browsers still support it, it is not recommended to use. Instead you can use `keydown` event.
[MDN Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/keypress_event)

And most importantly it supports of keys that produce a character value are **alphabetic, numeric, and punctuation keys**. To work with arrow key, you should use `keyup` or `keydown` event as your requirement. Here is the example of `keydown`:

```js
document.addEventListener('keydown', ({keyCode}) => {
  switch(keyCode){
    case 38: //key up in mac
      console.log('pressing key 38');
      alert('press')
    break;
  }
})
```

Comment: The event is deprecated *but still works*. It has not been removed. The deprecation is not the reason why it doesn't work when pressing up.

Comment: @VLAZ in my chrome browser(latest updated), `keypress` event doesn't invoke anymore. So in my case it's the deprecation.

Comment: Seems to work fine for me: https://i.imgur.com/h7faWFr.png See playground: https://jsbin.com/duvomequfu/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: @VLAZ update my answer. `keypress` event doesn't invoke with arrow keys, it only works with alphabetic, numeric, and punctuation keys.